# Prevent loading of jar from lib folder oozie

Tags: hive, oozie

I have a hive action in oozie and when this action runs along with the jars from shared lib it also loads the my application jar from ${workflowpath}/lib folder which causes jar conflicts and causes hive action to fail some times.

Is there a  way to disable loading of jars from lib  folder at action level.

Comment: No. You have to set up a custom Oozie "share lib" without the offending JARs and configure your action to use that lib instead of the default lib.

Comment: Or, configure your workflow not to use the "share libs" automatically, and copy _all the JARs from the share lib_ (minus the offendfing JARs) in the `lib/` sub-folder of your workflow.

Comment: Even better: recompile your **own JAR** to align with the same dependencies used by Oozie, with the same versions.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs i recompiled my jar to match with oozie and it resolved the issue